# Al instalar Visual Studio Code en Debian 10 me desinstala APT

Tags: python, linux, vscode, debian, raspberry

tengo un proyecto que estoy desarrollando en una Raspberry PI y como ya lo tengo funcional he decidido montar en VirtualBox la imagen de Debian que tiene en la propia pagina de Raspberry para descargar ( Adjunto imagen de la salida del terminal).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que instalo python y todo el rollo, quiero instalar o pycharm o visual studio code para poder realizar pruebas de una manera mas cómoda, ya que al utilizar los pines de la raspberry el programa en windows directamente no funciona.

Mi duda o consulta es con respecto a Visual Studio Code. Ya que cuando trato de instalarlo me elimina el paquete de APT, y esto la verdad no me tiene mucho sentido...
En la propia Raspberry lo instale sin ningun tipo de inconveniente, adjunto imagen del error que me da:

[image: error al instalar vs code apt]

La verdad buscando por internet no he encontrado gran cosa con respecto a este error, espero que alguien pueda brindarme alguna solución, algún otro IDE que tenga gestión de proyectos me seria también muy útil

Muchas gracias anticipado.

Saludos.

Comment: No entiendo bien cómo estás creando esa máquina virtual, pero si raspberry usa ARM, estás intentando instalar paquetes para amd64/intel64. Puede que tengas una incompatibilidad entre distribución linux y hardware.

Comment: @ChemaCortes muchas gracias por tu respuesta, yo cree la maquina virtual como un tipo "Other, ya que no me da la opción de escoger si amd/intel o arm. Entiendo que tengo un debian sin mas... pero bueno si choca por culpa de tenerlo montado en virtualbox. putada jeje